logic error in my routing function in node js
so I have a pretty common function for routing in my node project. But I'm dealing with a logic error I can't wrap my head around. As you see I want to render my HTML server side but when I create and serve it to the browser, the image links were broken. so I fix it with this condition and now my images are showing.
else if (parsedURL.pathname.startsWith("/public/")) {
    console.log("image");
    let imagePath = __dirname + parsedURL.pathname;
    fs.readFile(imagePath, (err, content) => {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end("Image not found!");
      } else {
        let mimeType = mimeTypes.lookup(imagePath);
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": mimeType });
        res.end(content);
      }
    });

but right now It seems like I can't respond to the queries because whatever I do I can't get inside the query block.
else if (parsedURL.query.id) {
    console.log("id");

how can I fix this problem and refactor my code?
(excuse me for my bad English)
full code:
// Create A Server That Can send back ststic files
const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");
const fs = require("fs");
const mimeTypes = require("mime-types");
const { lookup } = require("dns");

const database = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/database/movies.json`, "utf-8");
const cardTemplate = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/templates/movieCard.html`,
  "utf-8"
);
const mainPageTemp = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/templates/mainPage.html`,
  "utf-8"
);

// Creating our server
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // THIS IS A SERVER SIDE RENDERING SITE
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  let parsedURL = url.parse(req.url, true);
  //   console.log(parsedURL.query.id);
  if (parsedURL.pathname === "/" || parsedURL.pathname === "/main") {
    console.log("main");
    res.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-type": "text/html",
    });

    // 1. GET the 3 most recent posts from the database
    const latestPosts = JSON.parse(database).slice(0, 3);
    // 2. Get the card html template and generate 3 template ane save them inside a variable
    const cardsHtml = latestPosts
      .map((el) => {
        return cardTemplateReplacor(cardTemplate, el, parsedURL);
      })
      .join("\n");
    // console.log(cardsHtml);
    // 3. put them inside the mainpage.html template and send it to the enduser
    const output = mainPageTemp.replace(/{%POSTS%}/g, cardsHtml);
    res.end(output);
  } else if (parsedURL.query.id) {
    console.log("id");
  } else if (parsedURL.pathname.startsWith("/public/")) {
    console.log("image");
    let imagePath = __dirname + parsedURL.pathname;
    fs.readFile(imagePath, (err, content) => {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end("Image not found!");
      } else {
        let mimeType = mimeTypes.lookup(imagePath);
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": mimeType });
        res.end(content);
      }
    });
  }
});

const cardTemplateReplacor = function (template, card, url) {
  let imageLink = `/public/${card.cover}`;
  let moviePageLink = `${url.pathname}?id=${card.id}`;
  let output = template.replace(/{%IMAGELINK%}/g, imageLink);
  output = output.replace(/{%MOVIENAME%}/g, card.title);
  output = output.replace(/{%MOVIELINK%}/g, moviePageLink);
  return output;
};

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("We are listening to request sended to the port 8080");
});


I will have a lot of images on my pages, so I need a way to route my images in all my HTML pages. I tried tweaking my conditions but I haven't gotten any results so far.

I think you only have to reorder the conditions in your if-block:
if (parsedURL.query.id) {
  // ...
} else if (parsedURL.pathname === "/" || parsedURL.pathname === "/main") {
 // ...
} // etc.

This is because your moviePageLink is based on the main url, so the first condition will always be true and the second will never be reached.
Alternatively, you could add something to the moviePageLink so it will not match the first condition. For example:
let moviePageLink = `${url.pathname}movie?id=${card.id}`;

